# How to put JS code inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, components

I have a React component and the JS code that I would like to place in it. I tried it but totally messed it up. Does anyone know how to do it?

mycomponent.js

```
 import React from "react";
    import Navbar from "./Navbar";

    const Chat = props => (
      <div>
              //Place for my Js code
      </div>
    );

    export default Chat;
```

javascript code

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script>
        var socket = io();

        socket.on('message', function(msg){
          console.log(msg);
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;
        });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code inside `useEffect` hook. It will triggered once the component mounted.

> You have to install the `sockito.io` from the `npm`. Run > `npm i socket.io-client`

Adding few improvements as well.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const Chat = props => {
    const socket = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        connectToSocket();
        return () => {
            if (socket.current) {
                socket.current.disconnect()
            }
        }
    }, []);
    function connectToSocket() {
        console.log("Conneting to socket");
        socket.current = io('http://localhost:5000');
        socket.current.on('connect', () => console.log("Connected"));
        socket.current.on('disconnect', () => connectToSocket());
        socket.current.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;
        });
    }
    return (<div>
        Some data
        <div id="message"></div>
    </div>)
}
export default Chat;
```

Comment: the effect needs to be run only once (it is socket setup code). So dependency array should be set to  `[]`. Otherwise this code will be run on each render.

Comment: @Sohail thank you. And how about <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>, where should this link be?

Comment: @Sohail alright, I used your code, ran the server but I'm getting these errors in my console: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" and "polling-xhr.js:267 GET http://%3Csocket%20url%3E/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N38iOwA net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Comment: @Sohail used var socket = io('http://localhost:3000'); I have no ides which URL I should use here. I keep getting error : polling-xhr.js:267 POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N38kJib 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209426/discussion-between-sohail-and-petra-jakubcova).

Answer (score 0):

You should import socket.io from npm rather than using script tags in React. And the code be added like

```
import io from "socket.io";

const Chat = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let socket = io();

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
    });
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};
```